# Node.js+Express running on port 80, infinite ads requests

Tags: linux, node.js, express, amazon-ec2, terminal

I've started a new project with node.js + express on Ubuntu EC2 at amazon.
I've created an Express template and started the app with nodemon, but I've got a unexpected situation, when I run the project on port :3000 it works fine, but when I run it on port :80, it makes infinite requests to some yahoo advertising.

Does anyone had a similar problem? or knows what's causing it? or knows how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It looks like someone is making requests to your machine that are intended for `ads.yahoo.com` (i.e. those are inbound, not outbound requests).  Could be you have an IP address that used to belong to yahoo, or something?  What's the IP of that machine? (`dig <hostname>` from your machine).

Comment: Try spinning up another server and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know if this IP used to belong to yahoo, it has been set up automatically when i started the instance at amazon, what you said is the only thing that makes sense, i've checked out everything else, I did run another server... the same happens... i'll try start another instance. Thanks a lot !!